# Convert ASP.NET VB.NET code into C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Does anyone have recommendations on tools to use to convert an VB.NET ASP.NET Web Application Project into C#? The majority of the conversion tools do not support converting ASP.NET-based projects. Even the VBConversions tool (http://www.vbconversions.net) only converts the code-behind, but leaves all the VB.NET code snippets in the actual *.aspx file untouched.

Comment: The ASPX markup changes from VB to C# should be rather minimal, yea?

Comment: unless he's got a ton of <script runat=server> baggage...

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately with the legacy project that I am working with (which was originally ported from classic ASP), it's quite a lot of spaghetti code. :(

Comment: Well, that's a bummer :(

Answer (score 1):

I have tried C-Sharpener For VB & seems to be a good tool.
Please try this out.

http://www.elegancetech.com/CSVB/CSVB.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have never really had to do what you are saying but look at SharpDevelop. http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/ It has an option to convert pages to different code -- might work

Answer (score 0):

Code Converter is the best options. Its free a integrated totally integrated with Visual Studio

[Code Converter (VB - C#)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SharpDevelopTeam.CodeConverter)